# Does linux process rss memory include cached memory?

Tags: linux

I am trying to find actual memory used by the Linux process, I checked rss using ps command, but would like to know, does the rss includes cached memory of the process or not? If rss includes cache, how can I get exact memory process excluding cache?

Comment: RSS does not include OS level caches like FS cache

Comment: @that other guy, Os level caches, you are referring FS cache, but did rss include RAM cache in Linux?

Comment: FS data is cached in RAM. RAM data is cached in L3. Neither the FS cache nor the L3 cache is counted in RSS.

Comment: @that other guy, thanks that answers my questions, thanks for helping me to understand this.